# Working with Vuex with Vue and displaying data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vue.js, action, vuex

This is kind of a long explanation of an issue that I'm having on a personal project. Basically, I want to set a data property before my page loads when I read in data from a CSV file using D3.JS. I almost have it done but running into a small issue. Please read on to get more detail.

Basically, when the user comes to a page in my application, I want to display weather graphs. Like I said, I'm using D3.js to read in the data and created an action to do that. It works perfectly fine-I can console.log the data and I know its been read. However, in my vue instance I have a data property, which would hold the data set like this:

```
 data() {
  return {
    name: this.$store.state.name
    weatherData: this.$store.state.yearData
  }
}
```

I then want to ensure that the weatherData is filled, with data from the csv file so I display it on the page like this:

```
<p>{{ weatherData }}</p>
```

Nothing special here. When the page loads, weatherData is blank. But I have a beforeMount life cycle hook and if I comment out the only line in it then it will display the data. If I then refresh the page, fire the action to get the data and then uncomment out the line in the beforeMount hook then the data appears! So before I continue this is my full code for the store:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
 state: {
   name: 'Weather Data'
   yearData: []
  },
 getters: {
 },
 mutations: {
  setYearData(state, data) {
   state.yearData = data
  }
 },
actions: {
getYearData: ({commit}) => {
  d3.csv("../src/components/data/alaska.csv")
    .then(function(data){
      let yearData = []
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        let day = data[i].AKST
        yearData.push(day)
      }
      //console.log(yearData)
      commit('setYearData', yearData)
    })
  }
})
```

Here are parts of the vue file: The template:

```
  <p>{{ weatherData }}</p>
```

The Vue Intance:

```
 export default {
  name: 'Weather',
  data() {
    return {
      name: this.$store.state.name,
      weatherData: this.$store.state.yearData
    }
  },
  methods: {
     ...mapActions([
    'getYearData'
    ])
 },
beforeMount(){
  this.$store.dispatch('getYearData') //(un)Commenting out this line will make my data appear
}
```

}

Page when it loads: Notice empty array:
[image]

Then either comment out or comment the one line in the beforeMount hook and get this: THE DATA!!!

[image]

Again, my end goal is to have the action called and the data set before the page finishes loading. Finally, I know that I don't need VUEX but this project is further helping me understand it. Any guidance on why this is happening would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `mapState` instead of putting your data in the `data` object, which sometimes being late on updating the template.
just make your Vue instance to look like:

```
import {mapState} from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'Weather',
  data() {
    return { }
  },
computed:{
   ...mapState({
      name: state=>state.name,
      weatherData: state=>state.yearData
   })
},
  methods: {
     ...mapActions([
    'getYearData'
    ])
 },
beforeMount(){
  this.$store.dispatch('getYearData') //(un)Commenting out this line will make my data appear
}
```

thats way, you work directly with one source of truth-the store, and your `name` and `weatherData` will be reactive as well.

more about `mapState` here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper

Comment: Good day Efrat, thank you for the response and sorry for getting back so late! But this solution worked and thank you for the guidance that you provided! Have a great day!!

Comment: glad to be of help